# Cual es la pelicula con mayor existencias en inventario en cada tienda

Tags: mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo 2 tiendas en las cuales se venden varias peliculas, y la mayoria son similares, necesito un codigo de consulta de SQL que me muestre el nombre de la pelicula misma pelicula que tiene mayor numero de copias por cada tienda, junto con la tienda y la cantidad exacta. Lo he intentado usando este:

```
select film.title as Pelicula, count(*) as Cantidad
from film, store
where  store.store_id = film.film_id
```

pero solo da el nombre y la cantidad, y necesito tambien se muestre tanto la id de la tienda, como todas las tiendas

Comment: Agrega la estructura de las tablas por favor

Comment: ¿y de la tienda como vas a sacar cuál es si no tiene una columna que ayude a identificarla?

Answer (score 0):

Disculpa si tiene alguna errata pero, sin el dataset en SQL, he tenido que hacer la consulta de memoria y sin comprobarla. Te propongo algo así:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT store_id,MAX(n)
      FROM (
        SELECT store_id,
          film_id,COUNT(*) n
          FROM inventory
          GROUP BY 1,2
    ) c1 GROUP BY 1
) c2 JOIN (
    SELECT store_id,
      film_id,COUNT(*) n
      FROM inventory
      GROUP BY 1,2
) c3 USING(store_id,n)
JOIN store USING(store_id)
JOIN film USING(film_id);
```

Siempre en el supuesto de que en `inventory` registres más de una vez la misma película en cada tienda. En caso contrario, necesitarías un campo `cantidad` y la consulta cambiaría.

Ya me confirmas si te funciona. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Creo que le ayudaría mucho le expliques la forma en que haces las consultas relacionadas dado que el OP ocupa una sintaxis un tanto antigua, de modo que le sea un tanto mas clara

Comment: Tienes toda la razón. La verdad es que, mostrando los resultados de las consultas intermedias se vería de una forma mucho más clara... Si se anima a dejar el dataset con gusto le explico todas las conexiones